# Icon not displayed on Firefox OS Simulator

Tags: icons, firefox-os

I just started developing applications for firefox OS. I done a sample application and it is working perfectly. My issue is in my simulator my application Icon is not displayed. It uses the default icon.

I added the below code in my manifest file:

```
"icons": {
    "128": "Feed.png"
  }
```

Added a 128 x 128 image named Frrd.png to my directory. But it is not working for me, what can be the issue ?

Comment: I have a similar issue... my icon shows fine in the simulator but won't display on the actual device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First Answer:

Finally I got it.

For Firefox OS the icon size should be of size `30 X 30` or `60 X 60`.

For Firefox Market place the icon size should be `128 X 128`

> For Firefox OS icons should be provided without a drop shadow and a
>   close cropped canvas in the following sizes:
>
> ```
> 30 x 30
> 60 x 60
> ```
>
> **Note:** Firefox Marketplace requires all submitted apps to have a minimum of one icon that is at least 128 x 128.

Reference: [Firefox OS - Style Guide](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/styleguide/products/firefoxos/icons/)

---

## Actual Solution

I added all images with the dimensions specified in the doc to my application. But it also not worked !!!

Atlast I added a directory `img` to my project and added icons to it. Then modified the `manifest.webapp` file like:

```
"icons": {
    "128": "/img/Feed.png"
  }
```

It worked for me, I don't know whether it is a bug or not.

Comment: It should have still worked, those icon sizes are just recommendations for the best possible look! Adding a 128px is the minimum requirement.

Comment: @digitarald: Yeah, that is true. Even if I made it to 30 or 60. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox OS uses 30x30 and 60x60 icons

Answer (score 0):

Using manifest.webapp to add Manifest not URL in Firefox OS Simulator.

Comment: I didn't get you, what you mean by the above answer ?

Comment: I mean write manifest path not write URL in the input which placeholder is "URL for page or manifest.webapp". As 'http://localhost/manifest.webapp' not 'http://localhost/'.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
"icons": {
    "128": "/Feed.png"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, +1 @Midhun MP. Secondly, it seems to only work with top-level directories regardless of the directory name. Tested on the Firefox OS Simulator version 1.2

**Works:**

> "icons": {
>     "128" : "/icon/128.png"
>      }

**Doesn't Work**

> "icons": {
>     "128" : "/assets/icon/128.png"
>      }