# Firefox marketplaces doesn't show my application icon

Tags: firefox-os

I've registered my packaged application in `Firefox Marketplace` but it doesn't show it's icon. Here is my `manifest.webapp` icons part:

```
"icons": {
    "16": "/img/logo16.png",
    "32": "/img/logo32.png",
    "48": "/img/logo48.png",
    "64": "/img/logo64.png",
    "128": "/img/logo128.png"
},
```

and as you may know, Marketplace checks existence and dimensions of these files in submitted archive.

I think there is something wrong with my application and I want to know if it is possible to install such application on an `Android` device through `Firefox Browser`?

Comment: Please check my question and Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532832/icon-not-displayed-on-firefox-os-simulator

Comment: As you mentioned, providing icon in 128px size is necessary and I did so.

Comment: Did you added the image to seperate folder ? If not do it.

Comment: Does the icon appear when you install it via Simulator?

Comment: Yes it appears in Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that was their fault. Now marketplace shows my application icon.